# What is a Postgres query for setting a column value from an existing json value in the same table

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb

I thought I had this sorted, and it seemed very simple... but I'm trying to run a PostgresSQL query to copy a value from a JSON item stored in another, where there is currently a NULL value.

This seems to make sense, but no dice:

```
update
  table_name
set
  column_name = data ->> 'object_key_name'
where
  column_name = null;
```

Ideally the query would allow direct access to the JSON value in a dedicated column going forward verses having to do a JSON filter instead. I haven't had any luck modifying my query as from what I can see this should work...

An example table would be this, I believe:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (
    data jsonb null,
    column_name text null
)
INSERT INTO table_name (data, single_item)
VALUES ('{"object_key_name": "hello_world"}', null);
```

Comment: post table with data and show, how the result must look like

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean...

Comment: please reade https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query and see if is clearer

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] with the database schema definition, example data, and exact query you are using.

Comment: Hopefully the above is what is being requested?

Comment: After fixing a few syntax errors and typos, [that works just as expected](https://dbfiddle.uk/JgWg8-cl). What's the problem you experience?

Comment: I have a feeling I'm running the command incorrectly in the SQL UI I'm using in that case... but thanks for the clarification on the syntax issues, I don't do very much via direct SQL commands, mainly via a GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is misunderstanding of *null*. The standard relational operators (=, <>,  >, <, ...)  *do not operate on null*, any comparison operator returns **null** as the result. This also applies to arithmetic operators. When *null* is involved you must use `is null` or `is not null` or convert it (generally with the [colaesce](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL) function, but there are other ways also).  
For your issue you need *is null*: (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/TlVjZhrR))

```
update table_name
   set column_name = data ->> 'object_key_name'
 where column_name is null;
```

Comment: I believe I tried both = and IS - but I'll give it another try. Do I have to return all of the table values for the command to work, our of interest? As mentioned above, I'm using a GUI to run these commands so it may well be just a misunderstanding of Superbase too! Thank you.

Comment: Annnd got things to work. Turns out it was a silly mistake on my part with the table reference in the query! Thanks for your help clarifying the statement though.